# Мини-сочиение

Tags: этимология, пунктуация

- Мини-сочинение на тему: поэма блока 12 в 21-ом веке?
- P.S. : Не менее одной страницы листа обычной тетради по литературе.
- Извините если не по теме просто не нашел литературы на сайте вашем...

Comment: Зачем "материал" человеку, который не знает, что Блок - это поэт и пишется с заглавной?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот  материал:

http://www.kostyor.ru/student/school29.html

http://www.ymnik.ru/page.php?page=665&subs=296

http://gdz-otvet.ru/sochin/blok/zna%D2%B9enie-simvoli%D2%B9eskix-obrazov-v-poeme-a-bloka-dvenadcat/

Почитайте и напишите мини-сочинение.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот здесь](http://www.staratel.com/poems/begXX/block/dvenad.htm) более чем достаточно литературы для написания данного сочинения. Вместо вас никто писать сочинение не будет.